# Inner Join syntax without on

Tags: sql

If I have two table Orders and OrderDetails, what is the difference between two query?

```
select * from Orders o, OrderDetails d where o.OrderID = d.OrderID
```

and

```
select * from Orders o join OrderDetails d on o.OrderID = d.OrderID
```

Actually I get the same result but I want to know whether I can use the first query for inner join.

Answer (score 1):

The `on` keyword evaluates the expression *before* the join, the `where` keyword evaluates the expression *after* the join.

Comment: Do you mean they are equivalent and using `on` will be more efficiently as it evaluates the expression before the join?

Comment: @NickWan if you are just performing the query in your question, then yes there isn't a difference in the results